# Need to mass copy and rename files

Tags: batch-file, cmd, copy, rename

I have a large number of picture files that I need to use for importing into a database as style images. The files are for example A62PD_BLACK.png
I need to mass copy and rename

- A62PD**R**_BLACK.png
- A62PD**S**_BLACK.png
- A62PD**L**_BLACK.png
- A62PD**X**_BLACK.png
- A62PD**Y**_BLACK.png
- etc.

Is there a way to copy and rename all the files in the folder such that they each have the letter added? That is just one of the style names, I have a lot of different style names and colors. I know how to execute a batch file, and using the copying command in cmd one by one is a bit menial. Can someone help me out?

Comment: So you are saying you want to make 5 copies of each file with those 5 letters or are we somehow suppose to know what Letter to add?

Comment: Well, specifically those letters as its (stylename)(size)_(color).png since the picture for all the different sizes would be the same picture, I need to make multiple copies of the same image and then attach on different size letters. It would be R,S,L,X,Y for all styles.

Comment: I don't really mind doing it each time per style, it's just nuts copying/renaming one per size at a time

Comment: `for /f "delims=_ tokens=1,2" %%a in ('dir /b *.png') do for %%c in (R S L X Y) do copy %%a_%%b %%a%%c_%%b` NOte that `mklink /h` would be much faster but can only be used if the files aren't supposed to be overwritten later with different contents.

Comment: So all I need to do is copy that into a text file and save it with a .bat extension and run it in cmd?

Comment: @WellingtonChen, well, if it would be me I would first make sure I understand the code and then the answer would be obvious.

Answer (score -2):

Sounds like you need brace expansion: http://www.tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_03_04.html

However, cp only works on one destination at a time, so you'll also need to iterate. Try this:

`for dest in A62PD{R,S,L,X,Y}_BLACK.png
do
    cp A62PD_BLACK.png "${dest}"
done`

Comment: `batch-file` tag is only for DOS/Windows .bat files, see its description.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. My apologies.